# Elastic APM Java - Transactions & Spans are recorded but not reported to Elastic APM Server or Kibana

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-apm

I have a standalone JAVA application.
And have integrated it successfully with Elastic APM (+ElasticSearch +Kibana) for capturing telemetries.

**Java Version:** 8 - OpenJDK
**Elastic Agent & Library Version:** 1.16
**Elastic Search, APM and Kibana Version:** 7.7.1

Below are the relevant JVM Options being used:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:$BASE_HOME/agent-lib/elastic-apm-agent-1.16.0.jar -Delastic.apm.service_name=my-app -Delastic.apm.server_urls=http://elastic-apm-server:8200"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Delastic.apm.application_packages=com,org -Delastic.apm.span_frames_min_duration=-1ms"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Delastic.apm.log_file=$BASE_HOME/logs/apm.log -Delastic.apm.log_level=DEBUG"
```

- I am generating custom transactions and spans using the Tracer/Transaction/Span APIs as suggested in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/1.x/public-api.html).
- And as per the generated debug logs. These spans and transactions are getting captured as expected.
- I have validated the same by DEBUGGING it over the IDE, that transactions are being captured as expected.

## Problem: The custom transactions are not shown on the Kibana APM Dashboard

However some out of the box transactions from Quartz(which is being used in the application) are shown as expected. Which should mean the integration with the Elastic APM Server is fine.

It appears to me, even though the transactions are being captured successfully, those are not reported(sent) to the APM Server

**Refer some relevant apm logs:**

```
2020-07-01 12:33:09.569 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.ElasticApmTracer - startTransaction '' 00-d0025079170e4f03698702f4e68be4ac-cf792454fbef1c77-01 (16970dc3) {
2020-07-01 12:33:09.569 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.ElasticApmTracer - Activating 'ExtractionRequestHandler#invokeExtraction' 00-d0025079170e4f03698702f4e68be4ac-cf792454fbef1c77-01 (16970dc3) on thread 26
2020-07-01 12:33:09.569 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.transaction.AbstractSpan - increment references to 'ExtractionRequestHandler#invokeExtraction' 00-d0025079170e4f03698702f4e68be4ac-cf792454fbef1c77-01 (16970dc3) (2)
2020-07-01 12:33:09.569 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] DEBUG co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - Receiving SPAN event (sequence 86)
2020-07-01 12:33:09.570 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] DEBUG co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.transaction.AbstractSpan - decrement references to 'ExtractionRequestHandler#invokeExtraction' 00-98a1d8f4970d585915eb03a414b7b14c-994dd2823198f1ef-01 (33d448b5) (4)
2020-07-01 12:33:09.570 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] DEBUG co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.transaction.AbstractSpan - decrement references to 'BOpFileUtils#authorizeFilePath' 00-98a1d8f4970d585915eb03a414b7b14c-133200d1793fbaab-01 (67fba8aa) (0)
2020-07-01 12:33:09.570 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] DEBUG co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - Receiving SPAN event (sequence 87)
2020-07-01 12:33:09.570 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] DEBUG co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.transaction.AbstractSpan - decrement references to 'ExtractionRequestHandler#invokeExtraction' 00-98a1d8f4970d585915eb03a414b7b14c-994dd2823198f1ef-01 (33d448b5) (3)
2020-07-01 12:33:09.570 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] DEBUG co.elastic.apm.agent.impl.transaction.AbstractSpan - decrement references to 'SCR#init' 00-98a1d8f4970d585915eb03a414b7b14c-77cf207c33eb24ab-01 (2f1f25c3) (0)
```

## Need help in finding what I am doing wrong? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer after posting the same on **Elastic Support Forum**.
It was a very prompt response.
This was not a problem from Elastic APM side, and was more of a silly problem from my side.
Refer the [discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-apm-java-transactions-spans-are-recorded-but-not-reported-to-elastic-apm-server-or-kibana/239505) to find the problem and solution.